# Calculate a running total with an opening balance

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following example data:

```
Date        Amount  Running Total
01/08/2018  16111   16111
01/09/2018  15070   31181
01/10/2018  7361    38542
01/11/2018  4600    43142
01/12/2018  24862   68004
01/01/2019  10200   78204
01/02/2019  2320    80524
01/03/2019  13692   94216
01/04/2019  5938    100154
01/05/2019  2656    102810
01/06/2019  19550   122360
01/07/2019  15363   137723
01/08/2019  22155   159878
01/09/2019  22426   182304
01/10/2019  18693   200997
01/11/2019  12066   213063
01/12/2019  11414   224477
01/01/2020  3130    227607
01/02/2020  9849    237456
01/03/2020  7908    245364
01/04/2020  12724   258088
```

My running total calculation works fine if I show all the data in a chart:

```
Running Total =
IF (
    MIN ( DateTable[CalendarDate] )
        <= CALCULATE (
            MAX ( TransStats[Date] ),
            ALL ( TransStats )
        ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'TransStats'[Amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( DateTable[CalendarDate] ),
            ISONORAFTER (
                    DateTable[CalendarDate], MAX ( DateTable[CalendarDate] ), DESC
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However I want to show all TransStats data for the last 12 months and all TransStats data in the future (assuming today is 31/12/2019):

```
Date        Amount  Running Total
01/12/2018  24862   68004
01/01/2019  10200   78204
01/02/2019  2320    80524
01/03/2019  13692   94216
01/04/2019  5938    100154
01/05/2019  2656    102810
01/06/2019  19550   122360
01/07/2019  15363   137723
01/08/2019  22155   159878
01/09/2019  22426   182304
01/10/2019  18693   200997
01/11/2019  12066   213063
01/12/2019  11414   224477
01/01/2020  3130    227607
01/02/2020  9849    237456
01/03/2020  7908    245364
01/04/2020  12724   258088
```

Any ideas of how I could go about doing that and have the running total formula show the correct amount? Ideally, the dates from the date table without a matching amount in the TransStats table would not show either.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer:

```
Running Total Measure = 
var startPeriod = TODAY()-365
return 
if(
SELECTEDVALUE(TransStats[Date])>startPeriod,
CALCULATE(
    SUM('TransStats'[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('TransStats'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('TransStats'[Date], MAX('TransStats'[Date]),DESC) 
    )
),
BLANK()
)
```